# Wix: Revision control for files included in installer

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm already doing revision control for wix source codes but not doing revision control for files(to be installed). So, I can go back to old version of package source code, but cannot regenerate that package because I don't have old version of files(to be installed). I want to revision control for these files. Is there any other good method for revision controling those files or is it enough just to use ordinary scm software like git? I want to know some good practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a WiX question, it's a CM / Build Automation question.  The term you are looking for is "build reproducibility".  Some people put third party assets ( say nlog.dll ) in source control and some people put them in an 'archive' (network share)  and set the permissions to make it untouchable.  You then rebuild all of your application source using a label, changeset #, epoch, datetime  ectera depending on your SCC tool.  This creates all your other files and allows you to then rebuild your MSI.

The only practical consideration from a WiX point of view is that the default behavior is to generate a new PackageCode every single time.  In a reproducibility scenario you might want to archive the PackageCode of the orginial MSI and then pass this in as a static value to ensure that the reproduced build is exactly the same as the original.  Or you may decide to not due this and just document in your process the expected variation.